# Where is my app placed when deploying to JbossEAP using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I've successfully deployed an application `(app.ear)` inside of the application server `Jboss EAP 7.1` from `IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3`. I'd like to know where is the folder where it was deployed. I'm using windows and I was searching in this path:

> C:\Users\juanca\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\

However I couldn't find the folder. Any idea?

Comment: What's the purpose of needing to access the content?

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins, I have 3 applications (1 ear and 2 war) those are deployed successfully from `eclipse` with `jboss eap 7.1`, when I try to do the same using `IntelliJ`, it's not working, for that reason I wanted to know where the deployment folder is

Comment: If you're trying to determine why the deployment failed it would be best to look at the logs. Checking the deployment content won't do much good IMO.

Comment: Yes, I did, the log said some dependencies were missing, so I needed to check the deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for the solution, I found that `IntelliJ` uses the `tmp\vfs` folder inside the `Jboss` directory to deploy the applications, this is the path:

> $JBOSS_HOME\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment\

Answer (score -1):

`Hello`
Any deployment in stadalone mode JBoss will be in `$JBoss/standalone/deployments`. Or if you're using Domain mode will be in $JBoss/domain/deployments`.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ to deploy the app, in this case the ide doesn't use those folders to deploy

Comment: not sure what you mean, the deployment still be there.

Comment: This is incorrect. The `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments` is used for the deployment scanner. Any deployment done with CLI, the web console or other management means will not end up there. The deployment scanner does not work with domain so there is no `$JBOSS_HOME/domain/deployments` directory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.